# Improve Fractalize smoothness limit in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape

I'm vectoring a small raster image, and I want to use the extension Fractalize (Extensions > Modify Path) 
Unfortunately the smoothness parameter value is blocked at 10, and I want to use a greater value.
How can I break this limit of 10 ?

Comment: Hi, maybe you could contact the manufacturer of the extension?

Answer (score 1):

Inkscape's extensions are written in Python - which means the soruce code for the extension itself is available as a text-editable file in your system.

But for this cas, you don't even need to change the extension code itself - the accepted parameters are defined in an associate XML file which control the specifications for the extension. You an just edit that file in place, and the next time you start inkscape, it will accept your newly defined parameters -

So, locate in your computer a file called `fractalize.inx`  -you will see it is in a folder related to Inkscape install.
Open that file in a text editor (Notepad, sublime text, notepad++, etc) - (not on  a word processor, such as Microsoft Word or WordPad). Change the lines that read:

```
<param name="subdivs" type="int" _gui-text="Subdivisions:">6</param>
<param name="smooth" type="float" _gui-text="Smoothness:">4.0</param>
```

to include a `max` attribute, so they will read:

```
<param name="subdivs" type="int" _gui-text="Subdivisions:" max="30" >6</param>
<param name="smooth" type="float" _gui-text="Smoothness:" max="30" >4.0</param>
```

And voilá - the next time you start Inkscape, the maximum allowed for both attributes will be "30" rather than the default 10. (Just beware that the amount of processing used by fractalize is exponential, and a value much higher than 10 could take forever to complete - try just 11 or 12 to start)

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to add nodes to the path using first the function :
Modify Path > add nodes